# Angular: Get payload response from upload's api

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload, rxjs

With this code I can upload a file, but I can't get the payload reponse that is a base64 rappresentation of a new file.

```
this.http.post(config.url, formData, {
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).subscribre(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I tried different `responseType` (`blob`, `arraybuffer`, `text` and `json`) but in no case I get the base64 in payload.

EDIT 1: 
From web console the response is a bse64 string

but `subscribe` returns:

- `ArrayBuffer: {bytelength: 3717}` if `responseType` is `arraybuffer`
- `Blob: {size: 3717, type: 'application/octet-stream'}` if `responseType` is `blob`
- the body of request if `responseType` is `text`
- an error if `responseType` is `json`

Comment: `subscribre` ? pasting error ?

Comment: you till only get in payload what the API behind config.url returns as payload.

Comment: What do you get as response?

Comment: I edited my post to add the payload

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to convert the ArrayBuffer into base64 string

```
const base64= btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(res)));
```